# Find a basis for the subspace determined by the given line.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, vectors, problem-solving

> Find a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ determined by the line
>   $x=-3t .\ y=2t ,\ z=t$.

It seems to me that a basis for this subspace would be simply $\{t(-3,2,1)\}$, but could it really be so *basic*?

But I believe I understand how to find a basis for a solution space for a homogeneous system, which is the previous problem, and this seems of a similar nature, but it seems so much more involved than this so as to lead me to believe that it couldn't be so simple an answer as this.

Perhaps I am misunderstood?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is that basic. However, a basis is given by, for instance, $\{(-3,2,1)\}$. Remember that a basis consists of a single vector in this case (the space is one-dimensional), so $t$ has no business appearing in your final answer. What you've written is a full description of *all* the vectors in the subspace.

Comment: Thanks. This course is very confusing for me, because we have no reference material and all the problems are written by the professor (so I'm left to scour the internet when I'm uncertain of something). Everything is so abstract in this class.

I don't really see how it is that this could be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ when a set which is a basis for a vector space is required to have the same number of vectors in the set as the dimension of the vector space for which it's a basis in order to span and be linearly dependent. But, how could that be in this case? It seems there is only one vector.

Comment: @Alex You're told to find a basis, not for $\Bbb R^3$, but for the _subspace_ of $\Bbb R^3$ given by the three equations you have (such a set of equations is called a _parametrization_, by the way, in case you haven't picked that up yet). A basis for $\Bbb R^3$ _will_ consist of $3$ vectors.

Comment: Right! Yeah, I just noticed that. That was throwing me off. Thanks!